# Permission denied while trying to access localhost

Tags: php, localhost, fuseki

In PHP 7.2 on a Centos 7 machine, I'm trying to access an Apache Jena Fuseki 3.6 SPARQL endpoint.

Fuseki runs on port 3030, the name of the dataset is `ds` and I can successfully run `curl http://localhost:3030/ds` - while being logged in on that system even with a user without any rights.
Everything seems fine so far.

However, when I try in a PHP script to do `fopen("http://127.0.0.1:3030/ds","r");` or `fopen("http://localhost:3030/ds","r");` I always end up with `PHP Warning: fopen(http://localhost:3030/ds): failed to open stream: Permission denied`.

Fetching a file from the WWW or even from the very same Apache server like `fopen("http://localhost/mytest.html","r");` works though.

Are there any special permissions necessary for accessing a different localhost port? `firewalld` is deactivated, btw.

Comment: It sounds like you might have some conflicting DNS entry or something. What happens if you switch over to 100% IP-based `fopen()`?

Comment: Might be a good idea to attach either server logs or stack trace for php code

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I get that error both for localhost and 127.0.0.1

Comment: So you are running the PHP script on the same server as the SPARQL endpoint?

Comment: @georoot The warning I quote comes from Apache's log. There is nothing more in there.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yes, they are running on the same Virtual Machine - from which I can access the SPARQL endpoint via curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that SELinux is the cause of the problem, preventing Apache from doing outbound connections on other ports.

See here: http://sysadminsjourney.com/content/2010/02/01/apache-modproxy-error-13permission-denied-error-rhel/